# How to apply conditions on a child model's association from parent model in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following models:

1. Staff
2. Seminar
3. Schedule

Relations are simple:

```
class Staff < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :seminars
end

class Seminar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :staff
  has_many :schedules
  has_many :future_schedules, -> { future }, class_name: 'Schedule'
  has_many :past_schedules,   -> { past }, class_name: 'Schedule'
end

class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :seminar

  scope :future, -> { where('starts_at > ?', Time.now) }
  scope :past,   -> { where('ends_at > ?', Time.now) }
end
```

I can easily do: `seminar.future_schedules` & `seminar.past_schedules`, but here is the issue: I would like to have a way to get those seminars for a staff that have schedules in future.

What I have tried:

```
has_many :future_seminars, -> { future_schedules }, class_name: 'Seminar'
```

But the problem is: I can't pass `future_schedules` in above line, because it isn't a scope.

```
has_many :future_seminars, -> { where('schedules.starts_at > ?', Time.now) }, class_name: 'Seminar'
```

But it says: `schedules.starts_at` is not a column, and it is so. So is there anyway I can load `schedules` for seminars in advance using something like `includes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perhaps do something like this:

In Seminar model:

```
scope :future_seminars, -> { joins(:schedules).where("schedules.starts_at >", Time.current) }
```

In Staff model:

```
has_many :future_seminars, -> { future_seminars }, class_name: 'Seminar'
```

Also, I think there's a type in the scope for past schedules. It should be like this

```
scope :past, -> { where('ends_at < ?', Time.now) }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a highly performant method then you may need to blend in some SQL.

Something like:

```
Staff.find(32).seminars.
               where(Schedule.where("schedules.seminar_id = seminars.id").
                              where("schedules.starts_at > ?", Time.now).exists)
```